# condition for upper triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

Consider the following condition from this other [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4841/inverse-of-a-triangular-matrix-both-upper-lower-is-triangular/4904#4904)

1. Define $S_k = \operatorname{span} (e_1, \ldots, e_k)$, where $e_i$ the standard basis vectors. 
   Clearly, the linear map $T$ is upper triangular if and only if $T S_k \subset S_k$.

From this condition, wouldnt any linear map of dimension $\leq k$ be upper triangular? If not, what am I not understanding?

Comment: ... if and only if $TS_k \subset S_k$ **for all $k$**.

Comment: @DanielFischer What I am thinking is this: The transformation corresponding to matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ is definitely not upper triangular. But it is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: But for that, you don't have $AS_1 \subset S_1$.

Comment: I think I am confused by $AS_1$. What is the meaning?

Comment: Identifying the matrix with the linear map. The matrix for $T$ is upper triangular if and only if 1. $T e_1 = \lambda e_1$, 2. $T e_2 \in \operatorname{span}(e_1,\, e_2)$, 3. $T e_3 \in \operatorname{span}(e_1,\,e_2,\,e_3)$ 4. etc.

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus Daniel is right. Let $V$ be your space or dimension $n$. Then, for every square matrix $T$ of order $n$ and for every $x \in V$ of order $n$, $TX \in V$, which would make any $T$ triangular (just replace $x$ by the vectors $e_1,\dots,e_n$). You need the "for all $k$" part.

Answer (score 1):

The correct criterion is the following:

An $n\times n$ matrix $T$ is upper triangular if and only if $TS_k \subseteq S_k$ for all $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$.