# Upper Triangular Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the set $V$ of upper-triangular $n\times n$ matrices with elements in some ﬁeld $K$. I.e.,
if $A$ is such a matrix, $a_{ij} = 0$, for $i > j$

Show that non-degenerate upper-triangular matrices form a group with respect to
matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if $A$ is upper-triangular, then $A^{-1}$ is upper-triangular as well, and if $A,B$ are upper-triangular, then $AB$ is, too. This follows from the formulas for matrix multiplication. For different proofs of this see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4841/inverse-of-an-invertible-triangular-matrix-either-upper-or-lower-is-triangula?noredirect=1&lq=1). Since the identity is upper-triangular, the invertible upper-triangular matrices form a group, e.g., a subgroup of $GL(n,K)$.