# If $A$ can be factored as $LU$, is there always a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $DL^T=U$?

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ is symmetric, $L$ is lower triangular, $U$ is upper triangular. Maybe I am missing some fundamental insight here - but how can we be sure that there is always a $D$ such that $DL^T=U$?

In practice it seems to work, but I'm not sure how to argue that $D$ exists in general.

Comment: Does $L$ in $DL^T$ differ from $L$ in $LU$ or $A$ is symmetric?

Comment: may I know what  $U$ is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A=A^T$ and you have $A=LU$ with a lower-triangular invertible $L$ and an upper-triangular (echelon) $U$. Then on the one hand, the matrix $L^{-1}AL^{-T}$ is symmetric, and on the other hand, $L^{-1}AL^{-T}=UL^{-T}$ where the RHS is a product of two [upper-triangular matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4841/inverse-of-an-invertible-triangular-matrix-either-upper-or-lower-is-triangula), thus, an upper-triangular. The only upper-triangular matrix that is symmetric is diagonal, i.e. $UL^{-T}=D$, which gives $U=DL^T$.