# If $A$ is symmetric and nonsingular, with decomposition $A=LDM^T$, $L$ and $M$ is unit lower triangular, $D$ is diagonal matrix, show that $M=L$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a symmetric, non-singular matrix with decomposition $A=LDM^T$, $L$ and $M$ are unit lower triangular, and $D$ is diagonal matrix. Show that $M=L$.

Can I prove $LM^T=(ML^T)^T$ then $M=L$?

Comment: Are you assuming $A=A^T$? If yes then add it to the problem description. If no then $M=L$ is not true.

Comment: Thank you. Yes assuming A is symmetric matrix.

Comment: @Kevin Could you, please, add the condition $A=A^T$ to your problem statement? Otherwise it is not clear for those who miss reading the comment. My answer to other question ([see the link](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1442619/253273)) could be of some help.