# What is the use of reduced row echelon form (not a row echelon form)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

There is raw echelon form and reduced raw echelon form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form#Reduced_row_echelon_form

The row echelon form is used to solved the system of linear equations. What is the practical use of **reduced** raw echelon form?

Previous question in the forum was related to row echelon form (and not to reduced row echelon form):
[Is reducing a matrix to row echelon form useful at all?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1822/is-reducing-a-matrix-to-row-echelon-form-useful-at-all)

Thanks

Comment: @amWhy This question was marked as duplicate in error.

Comment: Can you use please remove the "duplicate" from the subject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the resolution of linear systems, Gaussian elimination is preferred over Gauss-Jordan (these parallel the echelon and reduced echelon forms) as the former involves less operations (roughly $n^3/3$ vs $n^3/2$), for a similar numerical stability.

Anyway, Gauss-Jordan does not require a backsubstitution step, which makes the code a little more compact. On the other hand, the reduced form is not compatible with LU decomposition.

From a theoretical point of view, the reduced form has the advantage of being uniquely defined for a given matrix.

Anyway, it is worth to note that for an invertible matrix, the reduced form is simply a unit matrix, totally uniniteresting. The concept is only useful for degenerate cases.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!